# Plugin error while starting Gulp local server

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I am using gulp and lately I faced an error which I was unable to fix by reinstalling the plugin, typing PATH to node_modules global variable or rebuilding scss. Also I tried newer version of gulp, but I rolled the project back to the beginning as it didn't work.

[image: Here is an error]

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone would get stuck in such situation. I solved it with simple "npm rebuild". That's all you need.